# How can I accurately program an automated "click" on Windows?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, winapi, windows

I wrote a program to click on an application automatically at scheduled time using Win32, using `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_UP`.  It usually works well, except I found that I need to put in a

```
sleep 0.1
```

between the `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_UP`.  (using Ruby, which allows sleeping a fraction of a second).

Without the sleep, sometimes the click doesn't go through.  But I noticed that sometimes, the click is "too long".  The click is actually on a Flash app's Right Arrow.  This right arrow will go to the next item on a list.  So if you `MOUSE_DOWN` for a little longer, it actually will shift 2 or 3 items instead of just 1 item.

So I wonder, is there a way to accurately simulate 1 click in this case.  Probably there is no `MOUSE_CLICK` event?  It has to be simulated using `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_UP`?

(it is actually called `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` on Win32, just for simplicity it is stated as `MOUSE_DOWN` instead.)

Comment: Given that you have kept the [perl] tag, I have to ask what part of my answer to your previous question on this does not solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007391/using-perl-python-or-ruby-how-to-write-a-program-to-click-on-the-screen-at-s/1009497#1009497

Comment: i started off using Win32:GUI but it needs some more installation, so I started looking into Ruby.  Does  Win32:GuiTest also need installation too?  If it is a click, then it may be better.  Does it send a click as a MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP separate by some time interval by using the timestamp?

Comment: @Jian Lin Looking at the source code, it seems to send a mouse down event immediately followed by a mouse up event (at the same location) with no delay in between. I guess I was thinking of double-clicks when I made the comment about delays. Win32::GuiTest also requires installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not decide what delay setting between mouse down and mouse up results in a valid single click, the operating system does.

No `sleep` function can guarantee the timing between the mouse down and mouse up events you want. Perl's [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.56/) module allows you to send an actual click event rather than messing with the timing of down and up events. **Later:** Looking at the source code, Win32::GuiTest seems to just fire mouse down and up events without any delay between them [see GuiTest.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KARASIK/Win32-GuiTest-1.56/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm):

```
elsif ( $item =~ /leftclick/i ) {
    SendLButtonDown ();
    SendLButtonUp ();
}
```

In addition, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(VS.85).aspx states that `mouse_event` has been superseded by `SendInput` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx which allows you to send a `MOUSEINPUT` event with timestamps etc.

Comment: is it true that the Flash app can still take that click to be longer than usual and shift 2 items?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not bound to a specific language you could have a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) which is made especially for things like this.
I had good experiences with it for automating things like mouseclicks or keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

What function(s) are you using to accomplish this?

I'd expect [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) with a chain of 2 passed in MOUSEINPUT structures (one button down, the other button up) would pull this off for you.  You can even play games with the timestamps on the faked events to more deterministic behavior than you'll get with sleep().

There's no CLICK to send, as its the responsibility of an application to collapse low level events (mouse move, button down, button up, key down, key up, etc.) into "user level" events.

---

Some code, to clarify.  This is straight-up untested/compiled C (read: the bad kind of C), but  I hope it illustrates my point.

```
LPINPUT events = (LPINPUT)malloc(sizeof(INPUT) * 2);

events[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
events[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
events[0].mi.time = 0; //Here, you can play with timestamps (milliseconds)
events[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
events[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
events[1].mi.time = 0; //Likewise

//Push both events into the event queue
SendInput(2, events, sizeof(INPUT));
```

I have zero Ruby experience, so I don't know how you'd interop this for your case.

Comment: I am using mouse_event = user32 'mouse_event' , ['L' , 'L' , 'L' , 'L' , 'L' ], 'V' and then mouse_event.call MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0 to send the event... how do I play with the timestamps instead of using sleep?

Comment: Added some code to illustrate how I'd try to do this in C.  Its completely untested, but hopefully helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 2 things:

1. I bet ruby doesn't and can't guarantee that sleep 0.1 really sleeps only 0.1 seconds. As this is probably out of rubys control and OS controlled
2. The call to the Win32 API via Win32 itself may take an arbitrary time and cause the delay

Answer (score 1):

Since the Windows API supports sleeping down to 1 millisecond, why not just sleep a shorter time? 0.01 seconds should be enough?

Comment: i think i have seen cases where 0.01 may not register as a click... but i can try more

Answer (score 1):

I'd use AutoHotKey. It's open source and free, been around a long time and actively maintained, to the point that others have built an IDE for it. I use it for generating unique random test data for form testing but it does mouse stuff too.

http://www.autohotkey.com/